# Why I can't navigate on Internet or ping external server after that I configured fixed IP on a Linux VM on VmWare?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, virtual-machines, nat, vmware-workstation

I am not so into networking and I have the following problem.

I installed Kali Linux on VMWare. I am using **NAT** networking mode.

The default networking settings use **DHCP** to assign the IP address to my VM and it works fine (I can navigate). I was trying to set a **fix IP** so I configured it in this way:

[image]

Where the **Gateway** value should be the IP address of my router. I obtained it performing **ipconfig** statement into the Windows shell of my host machine:

[image]

Then problem is that after that I restarted my Kali VM it appears connected but I can't navigate or ping nothing.

The fixed assigned IP seems to be correct:

[image]

Why is it not working? What I wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an IP address of 172.16.99.225 and a netmask of 255.255.255.0 your Gateway must be in the 172.16.99.0/24 range. 192.168.1.1 does not work here.

Set it on DHCP, note the correct values and use them to configure your static IP settings.

Comment: Ok, as I said I am not into networking....so the problem is that with that netmask I can't see the router IP address? So I set it to DHCP, I performed an ifconfig and I discovered that the automatically assigned address is 192.168.241.128 so it means that in theory I can set a static IP like 192.168.241.1 using 255.255.255.0 netmask. Is it my reasoning correct?

Comment: That is correct. On your router you should be able to see what IP range is used for DHCP. You should choose an IP outside that range to prevent duplicate used IPs.

Comment: if I see that correctly 192.168.241. **1** is the IP address of your host. So you should not use this IP, it is most probably the address you need to use as the gateway for your VM.